# To proving that the functions are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I know the definition of two functions say $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are equivalent if there exists two constants $0<c_1\leq c_2<\infty$ and $x_0>)$ such that
$$\Phi_1(c_1x)\leq \Phi_2(x)\leq \Phi_1(c_2x)\hspace{2cm}x\geq x_0$$

Now I have to show that the functions $\Phi_1(x) = \cosh(x)-1$ and $\Phi_2(x) = e^{|x|}-|x|-1$ are equivalent.
Below is what I am trying

$\Phi_1(x)=\cosh(x)-1=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}-1$

$\Phi_2(x)=e^{|x|}-|x|-1$
from here I do not know how to proceed, I need some hint only.

Comment: What's the main term in $\Phi_1$? What's the main term in $\Phi_2$? How does $\Phi_1(cx)$ compare to $\Phi_2(x)$, when $x$ is large?

Comment: Are you sure that in the definition it is $\Phi_1(c_1x)\leq \Phi_2(x)$, not $c_1\Phi_1(x)\le \Phi_2(x)$?

Comment: The definition of the equivalent function that I have written is from one of the paper that I am reading and later they say that the functions $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are equivalent so I tried to use the definition given in the paper.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean by main term? can you elaborate, I didn't understand what you are asking for. Thanks!

Comment: It means, the term that's much bigger than all the others (for large values of $x$).

Comment: Making any progress, Andyale?

Comment: @GerryMyerson not yet, I tried it but still not getting it properly.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your formula for $\cosh x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson why? the formula is $cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ only.

Comment: Look at what you've written in your comment, and then look at what you've written in the question – they're not the same.

Comment: Now I corrected so can you tell me how do we solve it any idea?

Comment: OK, so, we come back to the question I asked before: what's the main term in $\Phi_1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In $\Phi_1$ it will be $e^{x}$

Comment: Right! And the main term in $\Phi_2$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $e^{|x|}$

Comment: OK. So, the idea is that $\Phi_1$ is $(1/2)e^x$ plus much smaller stuff, and $\Phi_2$ is, for positive $x$, $e^x$ plus much smaller stuff. If you can find away to make the notion of "much smaller stuff" a bit more precise, then you're well on the way to proving what you want to prove.